# Is it possible to pass a JavaScript object to "Layers:"?

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers, web-mapping

I am trying to use the GetFeatureInfo functionality of Openlayers v3.

I am taking the layer name dynamically from the layerswitcher and trying to  pass it into WMS like:

```js
var temp=JSON.stringify(LayerName);
var newTemp = temp.replace(/"/g, "'");
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': newTemp},
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    });
```

Is it possible to pass a JavaScript object to "Layers:"?

If I pass the layer name directly it works smoothly but I need a dynamic functionality.

Comment: why are you replacing quotes? if LayerName is a simple string just use that in the LAYERS param. If it isn't a simple string then it won't work anyway

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var newTemp = temp.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

to

```
var newTemp = temp.replace(/"/g, '');
```

Replace double quotes with nothing not with single quotes.

Now you can add layers dynamically.....